# Warning: Unable to load SSH config file '/root/.ssh/config' in fabric

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, fabric

Below is my code:

```
from fabric.network import ssh_config
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.context_managers import cd

env.use_ssh_config = True

env.hosts = ['172.16.11.16','172.16.11.17','172.16.11.18']
env.user = "monitorx"
env.password = "x@345"

def list_files():
        with cd('/home/monitor/Ngrex'):
                run('ls')


def get_uname():
        run("uname -a")
```

When I run `fab list_files` then I get the below error:

> Warning: Unable to load SSH config file '/root/.ssh/config'

Any help?

Answer (score 11):

Found the solution. Simple create a file in .ssh/ directory with the name `config`:

```
touch /root/.ssh/config
```